# Sonatype Nexus cannot proxy jcenter.bintray.com

Tags: maven, nexus

I use sonatype nexus for maven repository proxing.
Our project need to use http://jcenter.bintray.com/ repository.
But if I add jcenter as a proxy to our nexus server, it does not work properly.
it seems a folder includes parent folder structures recursivly. something like the following.

```
a
b
c
    a
    b
    c
        a
        b
        c
            ....
```

Is this possible to proxy jcenter with sonatype nexus?

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue on Nexus 2.0.3. I can only see the folders as specified in the "Configuration" tab. Each time I go down a folder level, it's basically the same the parent folder structure. If I specify the "repository" in pom.xml directly without going through Nexus, I can get the artifact. Basically jcenter.bintray.com doesn't work through Nexus

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried pulling in artifacts through the JCenter remote proxy?
This should work as JCenter is a standard maven repository that's heavily used by all maven clients/repository managers. The issue may only be with the remote repository browsing in the Nexus UI.

Comment: What is the url of this jcenter remote proxy. The url http://jcenter.bintray.com/ seems to do weird stuff in the browser as well as when accessed through Nexus. There are also a whole bunch of checksum validation problems when going directly to it with Maven.

Comment: @ManfredMoser if you have a concrete example of a checksum error, rather than "weird stuff" and "a whole bunch of problems", we'd very much be interested in investigating it. This has has never been reported by anyone before, so if this is based on a true empiric observation, sharing an example would be most welcome.

Comment: I did a couple of trial. E.g. on a clean maven install with using just jcenter as mirrorOf I tried mvn help:system and it failed. I  just recall it was something about missing metadata files. When I tried the to build the android-maven-plugin it could not find the parent pom although it is in central. I did not keep log files of the runs but you should be able to reproduce. Also... when trying the same thing later .. it worked.

Comment: We traced it to jcenter pulling artifacts from central when they are not found initially and sometimes the timing seems to just not work out for the user. If you proxy jcenter AND central everything works.

Comment: And the checksum stuff... you will see the error message yourself if you try with Maven 3.1.1

Comment: We have built the android-maven-plugin multiple times with Maven 3.1.1 without a single checksum error, so I'm not sure what the source your problem was.
Anyway, if you are having further issues let us know and we'll be sure to look into them.

Comment: What is the JCenter remote proxy URL?

Comment: I don't find this to be very reliable. There may be some tweak, but I believe jcenter depends on individual Ivy-format repositories setting bits in their metadata that the content can be forwarded to jcenter. Or something weird like that. Just because there is a repo at dl.bintray.com does not mean the content from it will be at jcenter.bintray.com.

Answer (score 6):

As previously mentioned, pulling artifacts worked for me.
As proxy repo I used `https://jcenter.bintray.com/`

Browsing the repo is not possible, but gradle with the configured nexus successfully pulled out everything necessary.

Comment: This worked for me also. The important thing is to use https instead of http.